# DataSource And Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

how can i use object of data source that declared in aspx files in code behind ?

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetEntryByID"
        TypeName="Entry">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DbType="Guid" Name="id" QueryStringField="ID" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

my data source has an object named "ID" i am using Eval("ID") in asp file , how can i get it in code behind without calling select method and using that data source ?

more code :

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" BorderStyle="None">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <p style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 8px; background-color: #af9b9b; width: 475px;
                        line-height: 30px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
                        <span style="float: left;">View Count :
                            <%# Eval("View") %>
                        </span>

                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID","~/ShowStory.aspx?ID={0}") %>'
                            runat="server"><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink></p>
                    <p style="padding: 10px; padding-top: 0;">
                        <%# Eval("Text") %></p>
                    <p style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 8px; background-color: #af9b9b; width: 475px;
                        line-height: 30px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
                      Author : <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Visible=false Text=""><%# Eval("UserID") %></asp:Label><asp:Label
                          ID="lblUser2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></p>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

now i want to use membership.GetUser("ID").UserName to get user name via user provider key . and show it in `lblUser` how ?

Comment: are you using a gridview? or a repeater? can you show some more code?

Comment: nothing, i just want to get id from data source and get name of user in member ship by this id thand show it in label

Comment: Using `ObjectDataSource1` in the code behind gives you what?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're using the ObjectDataSource simply to get the user from the membership?  You're not using any of the related controls that consume ObjectDataSource?  Why not just simply use a SQL query to get the data?

Comment: More Code And Description Added

Answer (score 0):

`membership.GetUser(ObjectDataSource1.ID).UserName` would get you the user name of the user matching the `ID` property, if I'm understanding what you're asking.

To assign it to the `asp:Label` object would simply be

`lblUser.Text = membership.GetUser(ObjectDataSource1.ID).UserName`

Comment: ops , it doesnt work! i think that id retuturn ID of Data source (DataSourceName) using `<%# Membership.GetUser(Eval("UserID")).UserName.ToString() %>` solved my problem , any other way ?